# How to scrape options combination prices in homedepot

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrape

I'm trying to scrape products info from homedepot like price, product details, specifications, images, and s on. I was able to scrape all these information but now I don't know how to scrape the price if different combination of options selected in the product since the price is changing based on these options. Is there any way to scrape the price and image for each possible combination in the options in the product?

for more clear explanation to my problem see that product url

https://custom.homedepot.com/custom-doors/p/Steves-Sons-Regency-Modern-Customizable-Fiberglass-Door/314599913/45272-Pre-Hung/57533-Single-w-Two-Sidelites-Transom/57526-36-x-93/40069-12/57523-64-1-2-x-95-1-4/55572-Autumn-Wheat/45147-Left-Hand-Inswing/55578-Glass-Panels/45143-Black-Bronze/35734-6-9-16

you can see that there're some options in the right of the image each parameter has multiple options and each combination of these options when selected it changes the image and the price. If possible how can I scrape these info?

Note: I'm using selenium and BeautifulSoup

Update:

Here's my code so far for scraping the options part in the product page

```
def scrape_price(self):
    if self.soup.find("div", attrs={"class":"price-format__large price-format__main-price"}):
        price_div = self.soup.find("div", attrs={"class":"price-format__large price-format__main-price"})
        price_curr =  price_div.findAll("span")[0].text
        price_doll =  price_div.findAll("span")[1].text
        price_cent=""
        if len(price_div.findAll("span")) > 2:
            price_cent =  price_div.findAll("span")[2].text
        if price_cent != "":
            self.data['price']=price_curr+price_doll+"."+price_cent
        else:
            self.data['price']=price_curr+price_doll
    else:
        if self.soup.find("div",attrs={"class":"price-detailed__left-price-wrapper price-detailed__left-price-row"}):
            price_div = self.soup.find("div",attrs={"class":"price-detailed__left-price-wrapper price-detailed__left-price-row"})
            price_span = price_div.find("span",attrs={"class":"price-detailed__unit-price"}).find("span").text
            #unit_span = price_div.findAll("span")[1].text
            self.data['price']=price_span
        else:
            if self.soup.find("div", attrs={"class":"pricingReg"}):
                price_div = self.soup.find("div", attrs={"class":"pricingReg"})
                curr = price_div.find("span", attrs={"class":"price__currency"}).text
                dollars = price_div.find("span", attrs={"class":"price__dollars"}).text
                cents = price_div.find("span", attrs={"class":"price__cents"}).text
                price = curr+dollars+"."+cents
                self.data['price']=price
                self.data['Availability'] = "Available"
            else:
                self.data['Availability'] = "Not Available"

    if self.soup.find("div", attrs={"class":"price-detailed__left-price-wrapper price-detailed__left-price-row"}):
        detailed_price_tag = self.soup.find("div", attrs={"class":"price-detailed__left-price-wrapper price-detailed__left-price-row"})
        detailed_price = cleanhtml(detailed_price_tag.text)
        self.data["Detailed Price"] = detailed_price
        if self.soup.find("div", attrs={"class":"price-detailed__unit-cover"}):
            self.data["Case Unit Cover"] = self.soup.find("div", attrs={"class":"price-detailed__unit-cover"}).text


def scrape_images(self):
    if self.soup.findAll("button", attrs={'class':"mediagallery__imgblock"}):
        img_btns = self.soup.findAll("button", attrs={'class':"mediagallery__imgblock"})
        count=0
        self.data["images"]=[]
        for img_btn in img_btns:
            img_url = img_btn.find("img").get("src")
            self.data["images"].append(img_url)
            count+=1 
    else:
        if self.soup.find("div", attrs={"class":"styles__ThumbnailList-sc-10zajq9-5 gyXsdF"}):
            images_div = self.soup.find("div", attrs={"class":"styles__ThumbnailList-sc-10zajq9-5 gyXsdF"})
            images_divs = images_div.findAll("div", attrs={"class":"styles__ThumbnailInner-sc-10zajq9-1 icLycq"})
            imgs=[]
            for image_div in images_divs:
                if image_div.find("img"):
                    img_src = image_div.find("img").get("src")
                    imgs.append(img_src)
            self.data["images"]= imgs
def scrape_options(self):
    if self.soup.find("div", attrs={"class":"super-sku"}):
        param_tag = self.soup.find("div", attrs={"class":"super-sku"})
        params = param_tag.findAll("div", attrs={"class":"super-sku__inline-attribute"})
        parameters=[]
        for param in params:
            param_body = param.find("div", attrs={"class":"label"}).text
            cleaned_param = cleanhtml(param_body)
            splitted = cleaned_param.split(':')
            label = splitted[0]
            val = splitted[1]
            options_div=param.findAll("div", attrs={"class":"super-sku__inline-tile--space"})
            if len(options_div) == 0:
                options_div=param.findAll("button", attrs={"class":"super-sku__inline-swatch"})
            options=[]
            for opt_div in options_div:
                if opt_div.find("img"):
                    opt = { 
                        "img" : opt_div.find("img").get("src"),
                        "label":opt_div.find("img").get("title")
                    }
                else:
                    opt = opt_div.find("button").text
                options.append(opt)
            parameters.append({
                "Label":label,
                "Value":val,
                "Options":options
            })
        self.data["Parameters"] = parameters
    else:
        if self.soup.find("div", attrs={"class":"buybox__super-sku"}):
            options=[]
            options_divs = self.soup.find("div", attrs={"class":"buybox__super-sku"}).find_all("div",recursive=False)
            for option_div in options_divs:
                option={}
                optionheader0 = option_div.find("div", attrs={"class":"styles__HeaderRow-fb29x6-1"})
                optionheader1 = option_div.find("div", attrs={"class":"styles__Header-sc-1gql1zk-0"})
                if optionheader0 or optionheader1:
                    if optionheader0:
                        header_div = optionheader0
                    else:
                        header_div = optionheader1
                    if header_div.find("span", attrs={"class":"styles__Label-sc-1gql1zk-1"}):
                        label = header_div.find("span", attrs={"class":"styles__Label-sc-1gql1zk-1"}).text
                        option["Label"] = label
                    if header_div.find("span", attrs={"class":"styles__Value-sc-1gql1zk-2"}):
                        value = header_div.find("span", attrs={"class":"styles__Value-sc-1gql1zk-2"}).text
                        option["Value"] = value
                optionchoices0 = option_div.find("div", attrs={"class":"DefaultTemplate__FixedSizeChoiceImageWrapper-rpf825-0"})
                optionchoices1 = option_div.find("div", attrs={"class":"styles__TileSelectWrapper-jw86q8-1"})
                optionchoices2 = option_div.find("div", attrs={"class":"product_sku_Overlay_ListBoxes"})
                optionchoices3 = option_div.find("div", attrs={"class":"product_sku_Overlay_ColorSwtHolder"})
                if optionchoices0 or optionchoices1 or optionchoices2 or optionchoices3:
                    if optionchoices0:
                        choices_div = optionchoices0
                        choices=[]
                        choices_images=choices_div.findAll("div",attrs={"class":"styles__ChoiceImage-kykx13-4"})
                        for choice_div in choices_images:
                            if choice_div.find("img"):
                                choice_img = choice_div.find("img").get("src")
                                choice_val = choice_div.find("img").get("alt")
                                choices.append({
                                    "img":choice_img,
                                    "value":choice_val
                                })
                        option["choices"]=choices
                    elif optionchoices2:
                        choices_div = optionchoices2
                        choices=[]
                        choices_images=choices_div.findAll("span",attrs={"class":"drop-down__hover-effect"})
                        for choice_div in choices_images:
                            if choice_div.find("a"):
                                choice_text = choice_div.find("a").text
                                choices.append(choice_text)
                        option["choices"]=choices
                    elif optionchoices3:
                        choices_div = optionchoices3
                        choices=[]
                        choices_images=choices_div.findAll("li",attrs={"class":"styles__SwatchRoot-sc-1kr5yl9-1"})
                        for choice_div in choices_images:
                            if choice_div.find("img"):
                                choice_img = choice_div.find("img").get("src")
                                choice_val = choice_div.find("img").get("title")
                                choices.append({
                                    "img":choice_img,
                                    "value":choice_val
                                })
                        option["choices"]=choices
                    else:
                        choices_div = optionchoices1
                        choices=[]
                        choices_images=choices_div.findAll("div",attrs={"class":"styles__TileDiv-jw86q8-0"})
                        for choice_div in choices_images:
                            choice_text = choice_div.text
                            choices.append(choice_text)
                        option["choices"]=choices
                options.append(option)
            self.data["options"] = options
```

now I want to know how can I scrape the price for each combination of these options

Comment: Please show us your code, what exactly have you done, what errors you facing etc.

Comment: I'm not facing any errors I scraped title, price, imags, specifications, brand and all data in th page even the list of options. my problem is that I want to also scrape the image and price for each combination of options but I don't know how to accomplish this that's why I'm asking for ideas

Comment: Again, for this we have to see your code.

Comment: updated the question with code. so can you help me to give me any idea how can I accomplish what I need?

Comment: I will try. If not me - maybe someone else.

Comment: actually I was thinking of  looping for each parameter and select each option and enter combinations urls to scrape price and image but the problem that it will take a lot of time since for example in the product I mentioned in the question there are 8 parameters with different options by calculations it will make more than 1900 combination so I need another way. Also in that way I mentioned I don't have an idea how to loop on them to get all combinations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An important facet of the target page is that whenever an item is toggled (clicked or selected), additional pricing options can emerge. This solution recursively traverses the feature listing, clicking on each one, and continues the process on the rest of price listings once they appear:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time, re
d = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')
d.get('https://custom.homedepot.com/custom-doors/p/Steves-Sons-Regency-Modern-Customizable-Fiberglass-Door/314599913/45272-Pre-Hung/57533-Single-w-Two-Sidelites-Transom/57526-36-x-93/40069-12/57523-64-1-2-x-95-1-4/55572-Autumn-Wheat/45147-Left-Hand-Inswing/55578-Glass-Panels/45143-Black-Bronze/35733-4-9-16')
def get_combos(_seen):
   flag = False
   for i, a in enumerate(d.execute_script("""return document.querySelector('.buybox__super-sku').children""")):
       if i and i not in dict(_seen):
          flag = True
          for _s in ['.styles__BoxChoice-kykx13-3', '.styles__TileSelectWrapper-jw86q8-1', '.styles__SwatchRoot-sc-1kr5yl9-1', '.drop-down__hover-effect a']:
             p = f'.buybox__super-sku > div:nth-child({i+1}) {_s}'
             if (op1:=d.execute_script(f"""return document.querySelectorAll('{p}')""")):
                for j, _ in enumerate(op1):
                   try:
                       d.execute_script(f"""document.querySelectorAll('{p}')[{j}].click()""")
                       time.sleep(1)
                       yield from get_combos([*_seen, [i, [d.execute_script(f"""return (x => x === undefined ? 'n/a' : x.textContent)(document.querySelector('.buybox__super-sku').children[{i}].querySelector('.styles__Label-sc-1gql1zk-1'))"""), d.execute_script(f"""return (x => x === undefined ? 'n/a' : x.textContent)(document.querySelector('.buybox__super-sku').children[{i}].querySelector('.styles__Value-sc-1gql1zk-2'))""")]]])
                   except:
                      pass
                break
          break
   if not flag:
      yield {'price':d.execute_script("""return document.querySelector('span:nth-of-type(1).pReg').textContent"""), 
              'img':d.execute_script("""return document.querySelector('.styles__ThumbnailInner-sc-10zajq9-1.icLycq img').getAttribute('src')"""),
              'combo':_seen}
           
          
result = list(get_combos([]))
final_result = [{'price':f'{i["price"][:6]}.{i["price"][-2:]}', 'image':i['img'], **({re.sub(':\s*$', '', a):b for _, [a, b] in i['combo']})} for i in result]
```

Output:

```
[{'price': '$1,423.00', 'image': 'https://custom.homedepot.com/is/image/blinds/SIP0000009218?fmt=jpeg&fit=constrain,1&hei=100', 'Door Type': 'Pre-Hung', 'Door Configuration NEW': 'Single Door', 'Door Size (WxH) in.': '36 x 80', 'Total Door Frame Size (WxH) in.': '37 1/2 x 81 1/2', 'Door Color': 'Autumn Wheat', 'Door Handing': 'Left-Hand Inswing', 'Panel Type': 'Glass Panels', 'Hinge and Sill Color': 'Black-Bronze', 'Jamb Depth (in.)': '4 9/16'}, {'price': '$1,506.00', 'image': 'https://custom.homedepot.com/is/image/blinds/SIP0000009266?fmt=jpeg&fit=constrain,1&hei=100', 'Door Type': 'Pre-Hung', 'Door Configuration NEW': 'Single Door', 'Door Size (WxH) in.': '36 x 80', 'Total Door Frame Size (WxH) in.': '37 1/2 x 81 1/2', 'Door Color': 'Autumn Wheat', 'Door Handing': 'Left-Hand Inswing', 'Panel Type': 'Glass Panels', 'Hinge and Sill Color': 'Black-Bronze', 'Jamb Depth (in.)': '6 9/16'}, {'price': '$1,264.00', 'image': 'https://custom.homedepot.com/is/image/blinds/SIP0000009242?fmt=jpeg&fit=constrain,1&hei=100', 'Door Type': 'Pre-Hung', 'Door Configuration NEW': 'Single Door', 'Door Size (WxH) in.': '36 x 80', 'Total Door Frame Size (WxH) in.': '37 1/2 x 81 1/2', 'Door Color': 'Autumn Wheat', 'Door Handing': 'Left-Hand Inswing', 'Panel Type': 'V-Groove Panel', 'Hinge and Sill Color': 'Black-Bronze', 'Jamb Depth (in.)': '4 9/16'}, {'price': '$1,346.00', 'image': 'https://custom.homedepot.com/is/image/blinds/SIP0000009290?fmt=jpeg&fit=constrain,1&hei=100', 'Door Type': 'Pre-Hung', 'Door Configuration NEW': 'Single Door', 'Door Size (WxH) in.': '36 x 80', 'Total Door Frame Size (WxH) in.': '37 1/2 x 81 1/2', 'Door Color': 'Autumn Wheat', 'Door Handing': 'Left-Hand Inswing', 'Panel Type': 'V-Groove Panel', 'Hinge and Sill Color': 'Black-Bronze', 'Jamb Depth (in.)': '6 9/16'}, {'price': '$1,423.00', 'image': 'https://custom.homedepot.com/is/image/blinds/SIP0000009219?fmt=jpeg&fit=constrain,1&hei=100', 'Door Type': 'Pre-Hung', 'Door Configuration NEW': 'Single Door', 'Door Size (WxH) in.': '36 x 80', 'Total Door Frame Size (WxH) in.': '37 1/2 x 81 1/2', 'Door Color': 'Autumn Wheat', 'Door Handing': 'Right-Hand Inswing', 'Panel Type': 'Glass Panels', 'Hinge and Sill Color': 'Black-Bronze', 'Jamb Depth (in.)': '4 9/16'}, {'price': '$1,506.00', 'image': 'https://custom.homedepot.com/is/image/blinds/SIP0000009267?fmt=jpeg&fit=constrain,1&hei=100', 'Door Type': 'Pre-Hung', 'Door Configuration NEW': 'Single Door', 'Door Size (WxH) in.': '36 x 80', 'Total Door Frame Size (WxH) in.': '37 1/2 x 81 1/2', 'Door Color': 'Autumn Wheat', 'Door Handing': 'Right-Hand Inswing', 'Panel Type': 'Glass Panels', 'Hinge and Sill Color': 'Black-Bronze', 'Jamb Depth (in.)': '6 9/16'}, {'price': '$1,264.00', 'image': 'https://custom.homedepot.com/is/image/blinds/SIP0000009243?fmt=jpeg&fit=constrain,1&hei=100', 'Door Type': 'Pre-Hung', 'Door Configuration NEW': 'Single Door', 'Door Size (WxH) in.': '36 x 80', 'Total Door Frame Size (WxH) in.': '37 1/2 x 81 1/2', 'Door Color': 'Autumn Wheat', 'Door Handing': 'Right-Hand Inswing', 'Panel Type': 'V-Groove Panel', 'Hinge and Sill Color': 'Black-Bronze', 'Jamb Depth (in.)': '4 9/16'}, {'price': '$1,346.00', 'image': 'https://custom.homedepot.com/is/image/blinds/SIP0000009291?fmt=jpeg&fit=constrain,1&hei=100', 'Door Type': 'Pre-Hung', 'Door Configuration NEW': 'Single Door', 'Door Size (WxH) in.': '36 x 80', 'Total Door Frame Size (WxH) in.': '37 1/2 x 81 1/2', 'Door Color': 'Autumn Wheat', 'Door Handing': 'Right-Hand Inswing', 'Panel Type': 'V-Groove Panel', 'Hinge and Sill Color': 'Black-Bronze', 'Jamb Depth (in.)': '6 9/16'}, {'price': '$1,423.00', 'image': 'https://custom.homedepot.com/is/image/blinds/SIP0000009220?fmt=jpeg&fit=constrain,1&hei=100', 'Door Type': 'Pre-Hung', 'Door Configuration NEW': 'Single Door', 'Door Size (WxH) in.': '36 x 80', 'Total Door Frame Size (WxH) in.': '37 1/2 x 81 1/2', 'Door Color': 'Autumn Wheat', 'Door Handing': 'Left-Hand Outswing', 'Panel Type': 'Glass Panels', 'Hinge and Sill Color': 'Black-Bronze', 'Jamb Depth (in.)': '4 9/16'}, {'price': '$1,506.00', 'image': 'https://custom.homedepot.com/is/image/blinds/SIP0000009268?fmt=jpeg&fit=constrain,1&hei=100', 'Door Type': 'Pre-Hung', 'Door Configuration NEW': 'Single Door', 'Door Size (WxH) in.': '36 x 80', 'Total Door Frame Size (WxH) in.': '37 1/2 x 81 1/2', 'Door Color': 'Autumn Wheat', 'Door Handing': 'Left-Hand Outswing', 'Panel Type': 'Glass Panels', 'Hinge and Sill Color': 'Black-Bronze', 'Jamb Depth (in.)': '6 9/16'}]
```

Regarding a concurrent version of the above solution for use on many thousands of input links, there are a couple immediate particulars that should be addressed:

1. First, the hosting of your `selenium` instances. You can either spin up a number of `selenium` driver instances on your own machine or use a service like [Browserless](https://www.browserless.io/) to do this for you. `selenium` is very resource intensive, so a hosting service that can automatically handle many separate `selenium` instances is probably your best approach to take.
2. Second, the method by which to interact with the target pages. If you use a service like Browserless, you could pass a Javascript function to `driver.execute_script` with a specific timeout that will offload the page interactions to the service itself.

Below is a solution that maintains a pool of `selenium` driver instances with an `async` version of `get_combos`. These drivers can either point to a remote `selenium` instance (like Browserless) or local instances on your own machine.

First, the `async` implementation of `get_combos`:

```
import asyncio, functools
from selenium import webdriver
async def get_page_combos(d, link):
   d.get(link)
   async def get_combos(_seen):
      flag = False
      loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
      first_vals = await loop.run_in_executor(None, functools.partial(d.execute_script, """return document.querySelector('.buybox__super-sku').children"""))
      for i, a in enumerate(first_vals):
         if i and i not in dict(_seen):
            flag = True
            for _s in ['.styles__BoxChoice-kykx13-3', '.styles__TileSelectWrapper-jw86q8-1', '.styles__SwatchRoot-sc-1kr5yl9-1', '.drop-down__hover-effect a']:
                p = f'.buybox__super-sku > div:nth-child({i+1}) {_s}'
                loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
                if (op1:=(await loop.run_in_executor(None, functools.partial(d.execute_script, f"""return document.querySelectorAll('{p}')""")))):
                   for j, _ in enumerate(op1):
                      try:
                          loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
                          await loop.run_in_exector(None, functools.partial(d.execute_script, f"""document.querySelectorAll('{p}')[{j}].click()"""))
                          await asyncio.sleep(1)
                          new_vals = [(await loop.run_in_executor(None, functools.partial(d.execute_script, f"""return (x => x === undefined ? 'n/a' : x.textContent)(document.querySelector('.buybox__super-sku').children[{i}].querySelector('.styles__Label-sc-1gql1zk-1'))"""))), (await loop.run_in_executor(None, functools.partial(d.execute_script, f"""return (x => x === undefined ? 'n/a' : x.textContent)(document.querySelector('.buybox__super-sku').children[{i}].querySelector('.styles__Value-sc-1gql1zk-2'))""")))]
                          async for pl in get_combos([*_seen, [i, new_vals]]):
                             yield pl
                      except:
                         pass
                   break
            break
      if not flag:
         loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
         yield {'price':await loop.run_in_executor(None, functools.partial(d.execute_script, """return document.querySelector('span:nth-of-type(1).pReg').textContent""")), 
              'img':await loop.run_in_executor(None, functools.partial(d.execute_script, """return document.querySelector('.styles__ThumbnailInner-sc-10zajq9-1.icLycq img').getAttribute('src')""")),
              'combo':_seen}
   result = []
   async for i in get_combos([]):
      result.append(i)
   return result
```

Second, putting it all together:

```
async def main(links, instance_num = 10): #you can adjust the number of instances depending on your needs
    drivers = [webdriver.Chrome('<path>') for _ in range(instance_num)] #<path> can be substituted for a path to a local chromedriver executable or a url to a remote instance
    final_results = []
    while links:
       pairing = [(a, b) for a, b in zip(drivers, [links.pop(0) if links else None for _ in range(instance_num)]) if b]
       vals = await asyncio.gather(*[get_page_combos(*i) for i in pairing])
       final_results.extend(vals)
    return final_results
  
links = [...] #all your homedepot links to be crawled
all_page_vals = asyncio.run(main(links))
```

Comment: the code is causing a syntax error in this line

if (op1:=d.execute_script(f"""return document.querySelectorAll('{p}')""")): 

it points to  this operator :=

Comment: @SarahEldawody `:=` is an [assignment expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/), available in Python versions >= 3.8. Please see my recent edit, as I updated the solution to support versions < 3.8

Comment: Yes thank you, I realized that I was using python 3.7. I switched to 3.9 and its working fine now thank you

Comment: Can I also ask you another question because I have more than 20,000 page like this is their a way to reduce time while scraping this? I noticed that multi-threading isn't an option to be used with selenium so do you have an idea how can I reduce the time using selenium or there's another tool that I can use instead od selenium that allow multi-threading?

Comment: @SarahEldawody Please see my recent edit.